# How can a creature with the extraplanar subtype avoid being sent forcibly back to its native plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Theory here but this will be a Changeling with the extraplanar subtype from the Dark Template. The character is currently martial rogue and has huge dumps into skills for infiltration and subterfuge. Ideally I won't see combat but even without that I want ways to handle the inevitable the DM will be throwing at me. (Banishment and Dismissal)

I am unsure of ways to avoid those two things from happening to me as the concept of extraplanar is new to me entirely.

Also in the worst case of being sent back to my home plane what are some things I could get/obtain to get back to the material plane?

We have a no holds bar on source material anything labeled 3.5 works and next to nothing is unused in some way.

Answer (score 7):

Dimensional Anchor (spell): "Any creature or object struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel."

It doesn't list those forced movements in the examples, but in the examples it said, "including" meaning it's not limited to those examples (which were really just spells that weren't explicitly extra-dimensional, save for gate, I believe). It makes sense - just as sailors use physical anchors to prevent unwanted sea travel, so too can an extra dimensional being use a dimensional anchor to prevent unwanted dimensional travel.

You would have to see the banishments coming. Of course, you could get some type of auto-casting equipment...ring of counter spells? Countering the spell could work, but not quite what I meant...I can't think of anything else that would cast Dimensional Anchor on yourself, in response to being targeted by banishments. Perhaps you could finagle a [custom magic item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm) that is continuous to cast it on you when targeted? Ask your GM.

Of course an even more general way to defend against it is to have a really high will save. Many magic items do this on the relatively cheap. Barbarians can also rage, gaining will save. For a one level dip, and the feat to turn raging into an immediate action (allowing you to interrupt an action to rage, gaining the bonuses before it strikes), you would have a bit more protection. Of course, this protection is equivalent to Iron Will...but there are side benefits to the immediate rage other than the will bonus.

Comment: Which goes to show that you never know when casting that normally *offensive* spell on *yourself* will be a good idea. [It's just really weird when it actually is.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45271/8610)

Comment: lol. Well, I mean it makes sense. Sailors use anchors so they don't float off into the sea without wanting to. Why wouldn't extraplaner creatures do the same?

Comment: That's a cool enough analogy that you should consider adding it to the text to stave off naysayers.

Comment: Dimensional Shackles says hello! Now you just need a version that doesn't force you to bind your wrists and you're golden.

Comment: (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/dimensional-shackles btw, they're a real item. Can no longer edit the comment.)

Comment: Yeah. That would work. You could likely ask the DM to just make it take the bracers slot, instead of requiring them to be bound. Most would say you could do that for no extra cost, since it reduces the reasonable capabilities of it - you can't clamp bracers on an unwilling target, unless they are already bound, and it takes a magic item slot.

Comment: I like this answer but it also make me think there is a way I forget how but you can use your concentration check in place of your will save.. While also having your int mod add to your will save. Only issue is as I said I am non-combat oriented on this character so minimum magic and no real level dips.

Answer (score 3):

While Dimensional Anchor, either as a well timed scroll or an always-on custom magic item, works it has the downside of preventing beneficial forms of magical movement.

An alternate option is to enchant two always equipped weapons (armor/shield spikes, spiked gauntlets, etc) with the **Spellblade** weapon enchantment (*Player's Guide to Faerun* page 120), designating them to Dismissal and Banishment respectively.

> Spellblade: The wielder of a spellblade weapon is immune to a single
> spell chosen at the time the weapon is created. The selected spell
> must be one that is targeted against the wielder, not one that affects
> an area or creates an effect. When the wielder is next subjected to
> the chosen spell, the weapon absorbs it. On his next turn, he can opt
> to either let the spell drain harmlessly away or direct it at a new
> target as a free action. Strong abjuration; CL 13th; Craft Magic Arms
> and Armor, spell turning; Price 6,000 gp.

Answer (score 2):

[Dismissal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dismissal.htm) is negated by a Will save, so either have a good Will save or do not antagonise people with access to either that spell or the superior [Banishment.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/banishment.htm) Or invest in anti-caster measures.

As for getting back, [Gate](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gate.htm) is a good way but requires 9th level casting. For lower levels, [Plane Shift](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planeShift.htm) will do the trick (Cleric 5/Wizard 7) but it's less accurate since you appear 5d% (5 to 500) miles off from your destination. Though RAW suggest that going TO the Material rather than FROM it works differently.

Comment: Hey thanks again @Thomas I edited the question a bit to be a bit more clear about what I have to work with. Can Gate be obtained as a scroll or something similar?

Comment: Yep, but it costs a hefty 8825 gold, making it the fourth-most expensive scroll in the base game: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/scrolls.htm

Comment: I would be willing to take the 5d% on plane shift scroll due to the scale of our map. However I am interested in the RAW suggestion that going to the material plane works differently.

Comment: Ooo the comment above made a good point Dimensional Anchor is a cheap scroll alternative. Tho gate/planeshift is a must so I can get back home incase all else fails!