# Does the Augmented Humanoid subtype count the creature as humanoid for spell effects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Inspired by a comment thread on [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45230/how-can-i-thwart-a-vampire-in-the-party-planning-on-dominating-all-of-us)

The [vampire template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) says the following for the Type entry:

> Type: The creature's type changes to undead (augmented). Do not recalculate class Hit Dice, BAB, or saves.

Does a creature that acquires this template — with the *augmented* subtype — still count as their original type for targeting spells and effects? In concrete terms: if a humanoid becomes a vampire, will spells like [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) still work on them? Does this apply for other templates with similar *augmented* types?

Another user I respect said that Enlarge Person should still work on that previously-humanoid vampire, and whilst I strongly disagree, I can't find anything in the rules as written that specifically says they do not. I will self-answer below with support and examples, but a book rule, developer clarification, or FAQ would be better.  Barring that, other examples in the books could help us confirm or deny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Augmented [original type] as a subtype has the following description:

> A creature receives this subtype when something (usually a template) changes its original type. Some creatures (those with an inherited template) are born with this subtype; others acquire it when they take on an acquired template. The augmented subtype is always paired with the creature's original type.

It doesn't say anything about the creature continuing to be or count as a creature of its original type, and primarily seems to function as a way to remember what this creature was before it changed types.  The augmented subtype is typically applied when some part of a creature's statistics remain based on its old type:  for example, a [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) does not recalculate HD, hp, or BAB when becoming undead;  additionally, the vampire's create spawn ability only works on creatures of its original type.  A [ghoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul), however, despite being a former humanoid turned undead by an undead creature's special ability, exactly like a vampire, does not gain the augmented subtype.  A ghoul's statistics and traits, though, are not based on the original creature's;  not even the creature's race matters except perhaps to help determine appearance.  A ghoul's stats are set;  there's no "ghoul template" to apply.

The rules for [animal companions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) feel the need to call out companions as "remaining creatures of the animal type for the purposes of determining which spells can effect them", although animals whose Int score increases to 3 normally become magical beasts (augmented animal).  This implies that allowing the creature to change to a magical beast (augmented animal) would disqualify it from having spells like Animal Growth cast on it.  Indeed, the [Awaken spell on the Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken) specifically mentions that creatures targeted by it can no longer serve as animal companions.  Awaken causes them to become magical beasts (augmented animal), while an animal companion must be an animal.

After looking at which creatures do and don't gain the augmented subtype, I'm reasonably certain the correct use of the subtype is:  Apply the subtype if the creature's statistics are partially based on what the creature was before becoming its new type, or if it has abilities that rely on recalling its original creature type.  I'm sure that the original type no longer counts as its current type;  a creature can only have one type.  Part of the benefit of class archetypes that change your type is that you become immune to the many humanoid-only control spells, such as Dominate Person or Charm Person, and part of the drawback is that you can no longer be affected by humanoid-only buffs, such as Enlarge Person.  Otherwise the type change would be near-meaningless, and interpreting the rules in situations where one of your types is specifically vulnerable to an effect and the other type is not would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

The full creature type line of a previously [humanoid vampire](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/vampire.html#_vampire) is

> undead (augmented humanoid)

with the "humanoid" in the original PRD being a hyperlinked reference to the full [humanoid type](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#_humanoid), in case there is any doubt or ambiguity.

The [Enlarge Person](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/enlargePerson.html) spell's target line is

> **Target** one humanoid creature

Since *humanoid* is part of the type line of the vampire, it's a valid target for the spell.

---

There are undoubtedly contradictions and ambiguities elsewhere in the Pathfinder rules, but it seems straightforwardly RAW and RAI that vampires of humanoid body plan, with "humanoid" in their type line, are humanoid creatures — whatever else they may be in addition.

Comment: It does not have humanoid in its type line any more than a monstrous humanoid does, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Tharkon Yes it does. See first paragraph of answer.

Comment: That says augmented humanoid, not humanoid. Augmented humanoid may or may not count as humanoid for certain effects, not to sure about that. But is is not equal to it.

Comment: @Tharkon The *thesis* of my answer is that it does. I don’t expect everyone to agree. If you’re expecting me to reverse the answer to say the opposite of that thesis, why would I do that?